# CSS3 opacity animation no longer works on Firefox?

Tags: css, css-animations

I've made my backgrounds fade in with CSS3 here: http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/artistchannel.php

It works fine, but not in Firefox (newest beta).

The funny thing though is that my small pulse animation works fine: 
http://www.cphrecmedia.dk/musikdk/stage/chat.php

So it seems its the opacity-animation which wont work.

This is my code:

```
             .fadeIn{
                animation: fadein 1s;
                -moz-animation: fadein 1s; /* Firefox */
                -webkit-animation: fadein 1s; /* Safari and Chrome */
            }

            @keyframes fadein {
                from {
                    opacity:0;
                }
                to {
                    opacity:1;
                }
            }
            @-moz-keyframes fadein { /* Firefox */
                from {
                    opacity:0;
                }
                to {
                    opacity:1;
                }
            }
            @-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
                from {
                    opacity:0;
                }
                to {
                    opacity:1;
                }
            }
```

Anyone who knows whats wrong?

Comment: It might sound simple but have you tried placing the prefix-free version of the properties last?

Comment: Strange it actually worked! Is there any explanation why this fixes it?

Comment: I believe it is because Firefox no longer requires the -moz- prefix for some properties we're used to prefixing for so long. I ran into this once and it worked for me too.

Comment: @BJack this is the right way. Placing the prefix-free version last should let browsers that officially implement this feature (and not experimentally) ignore the previous rules. A newer version of a browser might eventually ignore vendor prefixes and only implement the official CSS rule.